# How to send an checkbox array and some other values with ajax jquery post through PHP MVC

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, model-view-controller

I'm trying to send data into database using AJAX/JQUERY/PHP(MVC);

I have a table with loads of data; the table contain checkboxes to check rows which can be sent to database.

For the **View** file; Im trying to send data like this:

## **Edited**

```
<form action="<?php echo URL ?>etudiants/affectation" method="POST" id="affectStudents"  class='form-vertical'>
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="input-append">
                <select name="id_salle" id="id_salle" class='input-medium'>
                    <option value="0">«Choisir Salle»</option>
                    <?php foreach($this->fetchSalle AS $key => $value): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value['id_salle'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $value['intitule_salle']; ?>
                    => C: <?php echo $value['capacite']; ?>
                    => M: <?php echo $value['marge']; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <button class="btn" type="submit"> Affecter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content nopadding">
        <table class="table table-hover table-nomargin table-bordered dataTable dataTable-nosort" data-nosort="0">
            <thead>
                <tr class='thefilter'>
                    <th class='with-checkbox'>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check_all" id="check_all"></th>
                    <th>Code Etud.</th>
                    <th>Filière</th>
                    <th>Nom et Prénom</th>
                    <th>CIN</th>
                    <th>Tel</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach($this->fetchEtudiants AS $value): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="with-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="id_etudiants[]" value="<?php echo $value['id_etudiant']; ?>" class="check_id" id="check_id">
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $value['code_etudiant']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value['intitule_filiere']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value['nom']; ?> 
                         <?php echo $value['prenom']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $value['cin']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value['tel']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value['email']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>    
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="csem" value="<?php echo @$_GET['csem'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cses" value="<?php echo @$_GET['cses'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cfil" value="<?php echo @$_GET['cfil'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmod" value="<?php echo @$_GET['cmod'] ?>">
</form>
```

Controller file

**etudiants.php**

```
class Etudiants extends Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();          
    }
    public function index(){        
        $this->view->render('etudiants/index');
    }

    function affectation(){
        $this->model->affectation();
    }   
}
```

**etudiants_model.php**

```
class Etudiants_Model extends Model
    {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function affectation(){
        $students[] = $_POST['id_etudiants'];
        $id_salle   = $_POST['id_salle'];

        for ($i=1; $i <= strlen($students) ; $i++) {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO exam_salles (id_student, id_salle) VALUES(?,?)");
            $stmt->execute(array($students[$i], $id_salle));
        }

        if($stmt == TRUE){
            echo "good";
        }else{
            echo "wrong";
        }
    }
}
```

for the JS file I used this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#affectStudents").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url     = $(this).attr('action');
    var data    = $(this).serialize();

    $.post(url, data, function(response) {
        if(response == 'good'){
            $("#affectedSuccessfully").show();
        }else{
            $("#affectedError").show();
        }           
    });                
});
});
```

When I Click the button **SEND** It redirect me to **/etudiants/affectation** even if I'm using the **preventDefault();** and send no data to database.

Comment: What happens when you console.log $("#affectStudents").  Make sure the JS is ran after the DOM is ready.

Comment: The HTML you posted says that SEND is a text field, not a button, are you sure you published the correct code?

Comment: I Updated the code, it was just a typo here

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded JS file well? Also jQuery library? It seems to be not done, your JS function.
Check also errors in debug bar, if there are some.

**Edit (after discussion)**:

http://jsfiddle.net/wvwm5Luz/2/
Your jQuery serialize method make each checkbox as one variable. In my opinion you can do this:

Use checkboxes without names. Get checked checkboxes (it is easy in dataTable plugin, http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2511/get-all-checked-checkboxes-in-the-datatable should help) and add it to `var data` in your `post`. Values could be in format like '1,3,8' etc. and in `etudiants_model.php` write something like:

```
$students = explode(',', $_POST['id_etudiants'];
```

After that I suppose it will work.

Comment: The JS file is loaded

Comment: Have you got any errors? Which version of jQuery have you loaded?

Comment: Try write `alert($("#affectStudents"));` before your function. Got you undefined or htmlelm or something like that? Or try `console.log($("#affectStudents"));` at the same place and write what you has been written to console. You can also add to your question which code works at the same place and doesn't work after your on(submit) function. We can look at differences.

Comment: I think the problem is with the check box input array, when I remove it, everything work fine. Did I did something wrong with the code above, the checkboxes? I believe when there multiple checkboxes we should make the name an Array, this ways, name="checkbox[]" and loop through it to store the POST values into database as I did in my code above NO?

Comment: I don't see any problem with checkboxes. I tried it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/wvwm5Luz/

However checkbox values are strange after serialize... With array in name it works well in PHP. What is the sense of your code?

Comment: I've edited View code above. 
Still not working, when I console.log data it returns all data except the values of id_etudiants[] array.... I'm still trying to find out the problem..

Comment: By the way, the table Im using is a datatable js plugin

Comment: I added solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are loading the javascript before the form is created, therefore the event handler runs before the affected element is created and as a result it does not affect the target element. You need to either register the handler after the page has been loaded

```
$(function() {
    $("#affectStudents").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url     = $(this).attr('action');
        var data    = $(this).serialize();

        $.post(url, data, function(response) {
            if(response == 'good'){
                $("#affectedSuccessfully").show();
            }else{
                $("#affectedError").show();
            }           
        }                 
    });
});
```

or, you can write a code which will expect the target to exist in the future

```
$("body").on('submit', "#affectStudents", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url     = $(this).attr('action');
    var data    = $(this).serialize();

    $.post(url, data, function(response) {
        if(response == 'good'){
            $("#affectedSuccessfully").show();
        }else{
            $("#affectedError").show();
        }           
    }                 
});
```

Comment: yeah i know, I'm using the $(document).ready();
I was just a typo here

Comment: Something wrong with this js file code Im using, I have another function inside this file, and its not working when I added the js code above but when I delete that code above, it all working fine.

It strange !!!

Comment: So, if you removed parts of the old code, then it was working well?

Comment: No, when I remove this code I put here, the old code which is used for another purpose works well.. This one here which is not working... I don't know why!